# Room, how to set 'field's notnull value' is false?

Tags: android, android-room

I want to add a new column in my database using room. I use Room's migration to migrate my database to a new version, but it doesn't work properly. Default notnull value of a INTERGER field is true, that 's really a trouble for me. Please help me. I has stucked in it for many hours.

I have a Location class.

```
package com.example.phamf.javamvvmapp.Model;
import ...

@Entity (tableName = "location")
public class Location {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private float x;

    private float y;

    private String name;


    public Location(int id, float x, float y, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Location () {

    }

    // Getter and setter
}
```

I want to add a new field which named type, its type is INTEGER so i modify my Location.java file above like

```
package com.example.phamf.javamvvmapp.Model;
import ...

@Entity (tableName = "location")
public class Location {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private int type;        

    private float x;

    private float y;

    private String name;


    public Location(int id, float x, float y, String name, int type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Location () {

    }

    // Getter and setter
}
```

Here is my RoomDatabase class.

```
    @Database(entities = {Location.class}, version = 2)
    public abstract class LocationRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static LocationRoomDatabase DATABASE;

    public static LocationRoomDatabase getDatabase (final Context context) {

        Migration migration = new Migration(1, 2) {
            @Override
            public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE location ADD type INTEGER");
            }
        };

        if (DATABASE == null) {
            DATABASE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, LocationRoomDatabase.class, "database")
                           .addMigrations(migration).build();
    }

        return DATABASE;
    }

    public abstract LocationDAO locationDAO();
}
```

Problem is when i run the code above, i get an error

```
//...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
   Migration didn't properly handle location(com.example.phamf.javamvvmapp.Model.Location).
Expected:
     TableInfo{..., type=Column{name='type', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
Found:
     TableInfo{..., type=Column{name='type', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

//...
```

The only different thing between Expected TableInfo and Found TableInfo is 'the notNull value'. Expected wants it to be true but Found doesn't. I realized the problems were right there so i modified my Migration code

```
        Migration migration = new Migration(1, 2) {
            @Override
            public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE location ADD type INTEGER not null");
            }
        };
```

I thought it would perfectly ran but then i got an error

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE location ADD type INTEGER not null
```

I also tried adding a default value to 'type' field but it doesn't work too

```
 private int type = 0;
```

Any way to solve this problem, please help me. Thank you so much.
Apologize for any error of grammar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this. By adding "DEFAULT someValue" after "... ADD COLUMN column_name" in the command of SQL. This make my field have a defaut value that matches with the expected table info.
i.e :

```
sql.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name INTEGER DEFAULT 1 not null")
```

Comment: But this is not the solution. If you apply this to your situation you will have exception with duplicate columns

Comment: This is what I had to resort to as well, with the exception of setting ```DEFAULT 1``` to ```DEFAULT 0```